# Python : Sum dictionary values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with the following layout /content
datetime,key_value_column
2022-02-02 00:00:01,"{'key1':2,'key2':7,'key3':100}"
2022-02-02 00:00:10,"{'key5':2,'key2':3,'key3':1,'key4':5}"

The datetime column is unique

I would like to have python script that sums the values in the dictionary for each row ie
2022-02-02 00:00:01,107
2022-02-02 00:00:10,11

I can read the file

````
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df)```

but no idea how to sum the dictionary values across the data frame  
I worked out summing values for a dictionary example below but I am  
 hoping to get some hints on how to process the dataframe  

```adict = {'key1':2,'key2':7,'key3':100}
sumvalues = adict.values()
print(sum(sumvalues))```

Thanks
````

Comment: Your csv is invalid as the dictionary is not quoted

Comment: thanks have corrected my post the file does have quoted dicts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are dictionaries and keys are numeric use lambda function only:

```
df['key_value_column'] = df['key_value_column'].apply(lambda x: sum(x.values()))
```

Or if there are string repr of dictonaries first replace them to dict by `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

df['key_value_column'] = df['key_value_column'].apply(lambda x: sum(ast.literal_eval(x).values()))
```

Comment: Thank you when I run df['key_value_column'] = df['key_value_column'].apply(lambda x: sum(x.values()))  I get AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @Shang - need second solution, because read data from file

Comment: thank you very much that worked will go and google it so I understand it, thank you all very much